# Linux Firewall Rules

Tags: firewall, iptables, linux-networking

I've configured firewall rules using iptables.   Outbound packets are being blocked.  It seems like outbound packets are enabled.  Does the use of bonding change anything, or do I just have incomplete rules?

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i bond0 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -o bond0 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -o bond1 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i bond1 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i bond1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i bond1 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i bond1 -j DROP
/sbin/service iptables save
```

Comment: 1) Can you reformat it so it's easier to read (indent commands 4 spaces so they become a code block.  2) Does this work without the firewall (so we know it's not the bonding that's the problem?) 3) Can you show us `iptables -nL OUTPUT` (indent 4 spaces...)

Comment: 1)Indented:/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i bond0 -j ACCEPT
    /sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -o bond0 -j ACCEPT
    /sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -o bond1 -j ACCEPT
    /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i bond1 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
    /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i bond1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
    /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i bond1 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
    /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i bond1 -j DROP
    /sbin/service iptables save

Comment: /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i bond0 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -o bond0 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -o bond1 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i bond1 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i bond1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i bond1 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i bond1 -j DROP
/sbin/service iptables save

Comment: 1) Indented
    /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i bond0 -j ACCEPT
    /sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -o bond0 -j ACCEPT
    /sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -o bond1 -j ACCEPT
    /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i bond1 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
    /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i bond1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
    /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i bond1 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
    /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i bond1 -j DROP
    /sbin/service iptables save

Comment: @IAPaddler you're supposed to *edit* your question and indent all outputs, like what @Zoredache had done. That said, please post the output of `iptables-save` (again, ***edit*** your question!)

Answer (score 1):

Bonding does not make a difference.

If that is the complete rule set, then your problem isn't that you are blocking outbound packets.  I suspect if you ran a capture on some device outside, you would see packets leaving your system, and you would even see replies.

The easiest way to fix this would be to simply use a couple stateful rules like these.  They will permit your system to make outbound connections, and the connection tracking will permit the response to be accepted on the INPUT side.

```
/sbin/iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW\,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -t filter -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```